# Path to translated content of a node

Tags: i18n-l10n

I need to find the url path to the translated node of a page , the Multilink Module seems to do just this, is there something similar for Drupal 8? How do I find the path to the translation of a node in Drupal 8?

thanx for your help

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use:

```
$japanese_node = $node->getTranslation('ja');
$japanese_link = $japanese_node->toUrl()->toString();
```

Adjust accordingly.